# Why do magic items only come from a certain part of my world?

Tags: magic

### How magic items are created

Let's split my earth-like world into two parts: part A and part B.
A part of the world can be something from a small group of islands to something like a big continent.

When a powerful person (a person with extraordinary skills, wealth or influence) dies in part A, one of their items becomes a magic item.
This is an automatic process and the item is something that has to do with why the person was powerful (like their sword when they were a skilled warrior).
When the same person would die in part B, this would not happen.
It doesn't matter where the person is actually from, it just matters where they die and how powerful they are.
These persons are also not all related to one another, at least not more than any two random strangers are.

Moving items from A to B or B to A doesn't change their magic properties: magic items work the same in part A and part B, they just don't originate from part B.

A dying powerful person is also the only source of magic items and living beings themselves are not magic.

---

### What magic items do

All magic items have an effect which the non-magic version of the item doesn't have.
This can be a lasting effect (like "a shoe which makes the wearer walk faster than normal") or an effect with a trigger (like "each time someone is hurt by this dagger there is a chance they will also get a mental illness").
The second example also shows that the effect doesn't have to be deterministic.

The effect depends on what the person did which died when this item became magic.
So one could say a part of the person lives on in the item.
That is why this only happens when *powerful* people die and also why this happens only when they *die* and not at any other moment in their life.

---

What would explain that this is happening in only one part of the world?

Comment: How do you define "powerful" person?

Comment: "one of their items becomes a magic item" : Is it an automatic process, or something that require some kind of action, like a ritual ?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Because part A is the Holy Land, imbued with magic since the old days when the Holy People were brought there in fulfilment of a Holy Promise and given the Holy Ark of the Holy Covenant to keep in the Holy Temple?

Comment: @AlexP How can i clarify my question to exclude the "holy land" explanation because this just begs the next question: Why is this the holy land and not part B? It seems kind of random to me, but fundamentally all answers are kind of random and I don't want to exclude all answers

Comment: Or one could say part A being the holy land may be more of a consequence of the "magic items when dying" mechanism than a reason for it

Comment: Palestine is the Holy Land because the One True Living God promised it to His Chosen People to conquer and rule. The Temple at Delphi is holy because when Zeus sent two eagles east and west they met over that place, which was thus consecrated as the [Navel of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos_of_Delphi). Why the Holy Land is *the* Holy Land is always justified by the myths of the specific religion for which that land is holy. I don't fully understand what exactly you are asking; do you want examples of holy places? Do you want somebody to develop a mythology for you?

Comment: @AlexP Palestine (or any holy land) is not really different from any other place in the world. Anyone could say anywhere "Hey this is the holy land". But part A in my world _is_ something special: it produces magic items. Maybe there will be people who say "This is the holy land" because of that but thats just a consequence of it, not a reason for why this part of the world behaves different from the other part.

Comment: What do you mean that Palestine and Delphi are not special? The Pythia at Delphi is divinely inspired by Apollo to foretell the future. To this day, each year on the Great Saturday, in the [Church of the Holy Sepulchre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_the_Holy_Sepulchre) the [Holy Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Fire) lights the Easter candles with an uncreated light; an unfailing annual miracle is not holy enough for you? (And historically Palestine has produced countless holy relics endowed with miraculous properties.) Only an Atheist would say that Palestine is not special.

Comment: Yes I'm an atheist so any holy land is not special to me. Not more special than any other cultural landmark. But in part A of my world there is something special. There is an effect which can be observed and verified. One could also say: if an atheist could say a holy land is not special then it means it's objectively not special, just subjectively. But part A is objectively special.

Comment: _What would explain these phenomena?_ -- Which phenomena are you referring to: why only one part of your world produces magic items, or because the created items have different and unique effects?

Comment: @Frostfyre I edited my question, the first is what I want: "why only one part of your world produces magic items"

Comment: In that case, I'm voting to close this question as _opinion-based_. This is your world and your magic system; we cannot define it for you. If you say that a part of the world produces magic items, then that part of the world produces magic items. If you then ask _why_ does that part of the world produce magic items, we'll just say, "Because you said so."

Comment: @Frostfyre isn't magic world building always opinion based then? Or is there a way I could have asked this question without being opinion based? Because I think the intent of my question is clear (and the answerers seem to get it): I want an in-world-explanation for why this magic-item-creation-phenomenon is bound to this region of the world other than "I said so"

Comment: Not all magic-related questions are off-topic. We can, and do, help _improve_ a magic system that has been defined, but we cannot define it for you. It's like asking why Person A can only summon lightning bolts while Person B can only throw fireballs. Without explaining how your magic system works, all we can say is, "Because you said so."

Comment: What is needed for a magic system in order to be "defined" enough for questions here? And is there a way to ask for ideas like the one I asked for so that the question will not get closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This hinges entirely on how you imagine the magic in your world works, and with a sufficient degree of handwavium, any and all explanations would be valid**.

Here are a few options, one as valid as the next:

**Magic conductivity**
One area of your world is conductive to magic, while the other is not. Meaning it can imbue items where the earth allows this, and the magic won't get through without sufficient conductivity.

**Magnetic interference**
Similar to above, imagine the earth being a large magnet. One pole attracts magic, the other repels it.

**Presence of natural resources**
Some underground and undiscovered natural resources could radiate magical energy in certain parts of the world, while they aren't present in other parts of the world. Or related to the first one, these resources could contribute towards the conductivity of magic.

**Ancient enchantments**
One or more ancient wizard(s) with core knowledge on how magic in your world works, have enchanted a certain area of your world with this effect, but the enchantment simply has a limited range.

**Aliens**
Aliens are hovering in a spaceship over one part of your world, and are playing a game of "hit the dead hero with a magic enchantment", and have been for millennia. It is sure to soon stop though, because their scoreboard is close to getting full. (a bit out there, but honestly, anything works)

Comment: You seem to have began to write your answer when I haven't yet made the edit to clarify what a powerful person is, so this may be more clear now

Comment: "This hinges entirely on how you imagine the magic in your world works": what exactly does one need to know? it is more like soft magic than hard magic, is this helpful?

Comment: @Marv I removed the bit about defining power. But "Soft magic" doesn't really help much. Magic is entirely fictional, and is unique to each world. There are no definitions other than the one you give it. If you say "It works like this" then that's it, that will be how it works in your world, and nobody can argue with you. How you explain why this is how it works, we can help give ideas, but ultimately you will choose what fits best with how you envision and imagine your magic to work.

Comment: Ok I will try to explain in more detail how the magic works in my question

Answer (score 3):

There is some form of magic [lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens) effect for an individual's power when they die.  The closer they are to the "focal point", the easier it is for them to become a magic item - and the stronger the item itself is (more power is contained, less is lost).  This might be a natural phenomena, or it might be artificial - that's up to you to decide.

Once you get too far away from the focal point, the lensing effect actually causes the power to *diverge*, and spread out, instead of compressing to form an item - like an out-of-focus camera producing a blurred and unusable photograph.  This "boundary" point happens to be at a natural barrier, such as in the oceans surrounding a continent, which makes it harder to observe.

Depending on how your lens works, you will either have a single "optimum point" or an "optimum ring" where the effect is most pronounced.  If the former, then this will probably wind up becoming the home of the local ruler or magical authority (Imperator or Archmage) - as the most likely location for their deathbed, it makes their death-item even stronger - reïnforcing the idea and legend of their personal power and/or "divine right".

(Not just longitude/latitude would be important here - altitude would also have an impact, as you try to hit a specific location on a virtual sphere...)

Answer (score 1):

- **God said so**
  Not the most interesting, but as soon as you have magic it becomes an option.
- **An ancient wizard cursed part B**
  The inverse of the god version, again it's an easy fallback
- **The university is in part A**
  Without a university education the magic users never become powerful enough to generate a magic item on death. Graduates tend to hang around the vicinity of the university rather than heading back home.
- **Part B is communist**
  Everything is held in common ownership, so the dying mage doesn't identify with any particular item. Which goes well with:
- **It's not about the dying person, it's about the people around them**
  With a high level of natural magic use, if people believe something will happen, then it will. People in part B don't believe in this effect, so it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

**The item must contain a substance that is only found in one region**

It could be anything:  a metal, or a special oil, or the fur of a rare animal. What matters is that only an object containing this substance can become magical on the owner's death.

The material only occurs in one region, and it's valuable, either because of this property or because it's rare. Because of this, only influential, rich, or talented people can obtain it. Rich patrons might deliberately gift it to certain people, hoping to collect a magical item later. These might often be stolen or resold.

Comment: So this would mean people from part B bringing their own items (without the substance) to part A and dying there would produce no magic items but I would like to have this in my world. On the other side I like that it opens up the possbility to actively bring this effect to part B by importing the substance or items with this substance.

Comment: Moving to part A would give them the opportunity to incorporate the substance into their possessions. Doing this might be a common custom among people who can get their hands on the stuff. They certainly have reason to want to give their stuff magic potential.

Answer (score 0):

**It's a perk of the local religion**

(I'm posting this separately to my other answer because it's a completely separate idea)

A person will only cause a magical item upon death if they have been blessed by a shaman of this religion in the last week. The religion is only practiced in region A, either because their method of blessing is a guarded secret or the religion is suppressed in region B.

Blessings like this are not something that any commoner can just get, it's restricted to those who can pay for it, or have clout, or maybe shamans are just very good at recognising innate 'power' within people and give blessings based on that.

Comment: FYI, you can edit your answer and add multiple reasons as and when you think of them, and have multiple approaches in one question like I did. Giving multiple answers [might not always be received well](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/posting-two-answers-in-a-question/5098#5098). (not saying you're doing it wrong, just some advice to consider)

Comment: True, I did consider that but my two answers were so unrelated I thought it was better to keep them separate. I'll edit this one to note that I left two answers. Thanks!